# How to validate Spark SQL expression without executing it?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to validate if spark-sql query is syntactically correct or not without actually running the query on the cluster.

Actual use case is that I am trying to develop a user interface, which accepts user to enter a spark-sql query and I should be able to verify if the query provided is syntactically correct or not.
Also if after parsing the query, I can give any recommendation about the query with respect to spark best practices that would be best.

Comment: How about executing: `val new = spark.sql(query)` - it will be parsed, but the query will not be executed. If there was an exception - then the syntax is most probably wrong...

Answer (score 8):

### SparkSqlParser

Spark SQL uses [SparkSqlParser](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkSqlParser.scala) as the parser for Spark SQL expressions.

You can access `SparkSqlParser` using `SparkSession` (and `SessionState`) as follows:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...
val parser = spark.sessionState.sqlParser

scala> parser.parseExpression("select * from table")
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression = ('select * 'from) AS table#0
```

---

**TIP**: Enable `INFO` logging level for `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser` logger to see what happens inside.

### SparkSession.sql Method

That alone won't give you the most bullet-proof shield against incorrect SQL expressions and think [sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@sql(sqlText:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) method is a better fit.

> **sql(sqlText: String): DataFrame** Executes a SQL query using Spark, returning the result as a DataFrame. The dialect that is used for SQL parsing can be configured with 'spark.sql.dialect'.

See both in action below.

```
scala> parser.parseExpression("hello world")
res5: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression = 'hello AS world#2

scala> spark.sql("hello world")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input 'hello' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'DESC', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'SHOW', 'USE', 'DROP', 'ALTER', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'START', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'LIST', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD'}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
hello world
^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:638)
  ... 49 elided
```

#### WARNING

`SparkSession.sql` comes with a (hidden) cost. Most (if not all) SQL statements will actually be executed. In other words, `spark.sql("drop table t1")` **will** drop table `t1`.

This is because SQL statements are [RunnableCommand](https://books.japila.pl/spark-sql-internals/logical-operators/RunnableCommand)s that happen to be executed eagerly at the logical phase of query execution (that happens on the driver).

Comment: So it is not possible to validate a query without executing it ?

Comment: It is. See that part about SparkSqlParser. A more sophisticated validation would require logical validation (i.e. checking whether tables, columns and types match). I think it's possible using QueryExecution and a few logical operators. What validation do you think about?

Comment: For my case, I am thinking especially about the syntactical validation of the query (which I guess happens in an early stage of Catalyst), and also checking whether query selected columns exist in the view (which I think happens in a subsequent stage)

Comment: Warning to the uninitiated: Running DDL through `spark.sql(...)` will actually execute the DDL. So `spark.sql("drop table t1")` will drop table `t1`.

Answer (score 4):

I found few issues using `SparkSqlParser` and it didn't support my use case. For instance, below valid Spark SQL dialect threw an exception,

```scala
val parser = spark.sessionState.sqlParser
val query = "select * from a.b where datamonth = '202203' limit 10"
parser.parseExpression(query)
```

**Exception**

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
mismatched input '.' expecting {<EOF>, '-'}(line 1, pos 15)

== SQL ==
select * from a.b where datamonth = '202203' limit 10
---------------^^^
```

## Solution

So, below solution based on `explain()` helped me with syntactic and logical correctness.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExplainMode

import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def validateQuery(query: String) = Try(spark.sql(query).queryExecution.explainString(ExplainMode.fromString("simple"))) match {
    case Success(plan) => "SUCCESS"  + plan
    case Failure(ex) => "FAILURE => " + ex.getMessage
}
```

**Test 1 - Valid query**

```
validQuery: String = select * from bi.booking where datamonth = '202203' limit 10

"SUCCESS== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit 10
+- FileScan parquet bi.booking[booking_id#1337613396L,page_type_id#13397L,platform_id#13398L,page_type_platform#13399,... 5 more fields] Batched: false, DataFilters: [], Format: Parquet, Loc...
```

**Test 2 - Syntactically invalid query**

```
invalidQuery: String = select * from bi.booking datamonth = '202203' limit 10

"FAILURE =>
mismatched input '=' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 47)

== SQL ==
select * from bi.booking datamonth = '202203' limit 10
-------------------------------^^^
"
```

**Test 3 - Query with non existing table**

```
noTableQuery: String = select * from a.b where datamonth = '202203' limit 10

"FAILURE => Table or view not found: a.b; line 1 pos 14;
'GlobalLimit 10
+- 'LocalLimit 10
   +- 'Project [*]
      +- 'Filter ('datamonth = 202203)
         +- 'UnresolvedRelation [a, b], [], false
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to skip table/column exist validation? For example , first statement is to create table and second is to do select on this new table. If we do validation on second statement(without running) it will fail because table does not exist. However syntactically the query is correct.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Schema validation will still fail

Answer (score 2):

Following @JacekLaskowski 's answer, I found that `SparkSqlParser` gave me all sorts of errors that were not really syntax errors.

I therefore agree with him and suggest simply throwing it into `SparkSession.sql`, which works fine. This is what my method looks like:

```
  /**
   * Validates a Spark SQL statement by trying to execute it and checking
   * if there are no syntax-related exceptions.
   */
  def validate(sqlStatement: String): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
    try {
      spark.sql(sqlStatement)
    } catch {
      case ex: ParseException => throw new MyCustomException("Invalid Spark SQL", ex)
      case _: AnalysisException => // Syntax was correct
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For **PySpark** you can use the following

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.utils import ParseException


spark_session = SparkSession \ 
    .builder \
    .master("local[1]") \
    .appName('test') \
    .getOrCreate()

try:
    parser = spark_session._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser()
    parser.parseExpression(query_string)
    print('Validation successful')
except ParseException as e:
    # do something
```