# pyspark sql query syntax checking

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am looking for a way to check syntax of a sql query entered to be executed in a pyspark environment. But i want to validate if the query entered is syntactically correct or not, before executing it. Something like ParseSqlQuery(sqlExpression).

Though i found  a similar question being asked(on scala API) and answered also(partially came to end suggestion as spark.sql(sqlExpression) as better fit). But since then is there anything developed to do it in a parser way?  Here is the link- [How to validate SQL expression (in user frontend) without executing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973729/how-to-validate-sql-expression-in-user-frontend-without-executing-it)

If someone came across with a similar scenario and got it solved, sharing will be a great help. Thanks.